# Flexible UITableview's height and Fix ImageView on top of it in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I want to create a ViewController with a ImageView on top, and a uitableview below it with flexible height in storyboard. I have been reading autolayout for a while with no success. any other ideas?

thanks

Comment: A bit more explanation of what you have tried and maybe a diagram of what you want it to look like vs what it looks like with your failed attempts would be helpful here. But, assuming I understand exactly what you're trying to go for here, you could have a UIImageView up top that is pinned left/top/right to superview and either height or aspect ratio. Then add a UITableView that is positioned just below the image, then pin the vertical space between the table and the image, and pin left/right/bottom to superview so it is dynamically sized.

Comment: actually i got it working, but after your description, i am now even more clearer now. thanks a lot.